# Nenhuma fila de análise disponível para você

Tags: suporte

Minha fila de análises está acusando isso:

> Você votou em perguntas da fila de fechamento em desacordo com os
>   padrões da comunidade. Por favor esteja mais atento nas próximas
>   análises. Dúvidas podem ser debatidas no
>   https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11910/estouro-de-pilha
>
> Volte em 3 dias para continuar a análise.

Sinceramente não entendi o motivo.

Como faço para saber "onde errei"?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Em geral o sistema manda alguns testes para ver se você está votando de forma consciente ou só dando votos a esmo sem pensar. E você falhou nisso em um grande número de vezes.

Há pessoas que saem votando só para alcançar medalha sem nenhum critério e isto não é permitido. Se quer ajudar, faça direitinho.

Claro que pode dar um falso positivo e você não faz isso, faz com seu critério. Mas ele é muito diferente do critério do resto da comunidade, então no fundo é considerado erro da mesma forma, provavelmente porque não entendeu como deve votar. Em qualquer caso, o sistema considerou que não está contribuindo positivamente.

Se não é o primeiro, veja como os outros votam e tente aprender como seria mais adequado votar na fila de análise. Mas pelo que eu vejo acontecer quase sempre é o primeiro, porque ele costuma mandar uns absurdos bem grandes antes de fazer esse bloqueio.

Gaste um tempo em cada caso, analise, e se ficar na dúvida, pule, muito eventualmente peça ajuda no chat.

Eu vi que tem fila com muita falha mesmo. E o sistema foi avisando delas.

Os próximos bloqueios serão maiores e poderão praticamente impedir de participar outra vez até porque um moderador pode fazê-lo quando percebe que tem muito erro.

Comment: Estranho porque nos testes devo ter uns 90% acerto. Tiveram 2 testes, em que eu até hoje confirmo minha resposta como diferente, tanto que, "errei" mais de 1x no mesmo. É difícil aprender "como votar" sem saber em qual tipo de análise estou errando mais. Vejo muito voto "fechar" com classificação "nada a ver". Confesso que, depois disso, em parte fiquei desmotivado para análises, principalmente por não ter como saber detalhado o motivo. Penso que, a análise é uma mínima forma de contribuir pelo tanto que o portal me ensina e me é útil. Mas agora pensando bem, estou fazendo ao contrário.

Comment: Não, as estatísticas de erro são absurdamente mais que 10%.

Comment: @rbz se você pode começar consultando outros com mais experiencia, via chat, assim você vai aprendendo aos poucos como a comunidade analisa, pois mesmo que muitos pensem diferente, há sempre umn ponto em comum entre todos, senão o sistema bloquearia geral. Na duvida, pule, ou pergunte no chat para obter mais opiniões, eu particularmente nem visito mais fila de fechamento, mas as demais, costumo consultar outros colegas do site, quando não estou muito certo do que fazer.

Comment: @Articuno Eu entendi, mas até então onde entendi o funcionamento, a análise requer 4 ou 5 votos para realizar a ação, ou seja, isso já seria um outro filtro em cima disso. O que estou dizendo é que (além de não ter ciência de que estava tão errado) agora nem sei qual análise estou errando. Tenho 2 opções: fazer como disse, via chat, ou somente em TAG que tenho mais conhecimento, e com 100% de certeza. Só queria "agregar" mais ao portal, e não ser somente um "perguntador" que usa o SO como ferramenta de trabalho, entende!?

Comment: Me tirem uma dúvida: o critério do bloqueio é somente pelos testes aplicados?

Comment: @Articuno E onde fica esse chat com esse pessoal?

Comment: @rbz na sua pergunta, dentro do aviso, tem um link, ele redireciona pro chat daqui.

Comment: Fazer em *tag* que tem conhecimento é pressuposto básico. Já estão entendendo o que errava. 100% de certeza é o mais adequado. Pode errar um algum caso, mas será pouco. Até onde eu sei foi bloqueado só por causa dos testes falhados, mas não quer dizer que não possa ser por outro motivos, até porque tentar burlar sempre é um problema, o que pode ser até pior quando fica evidenciado que há má fé.

Comment: "*E você falou nisso*" ou "*E você falhou nisso*"?

Comment: "*até porque um moderador pode fazê-lo quando percebe que tem muito erro*" - Não entendi isso.

Comment: @VictorStafusa manualmente um moderador pode suspender da fila de análise quando ele vê que um usuário erra demais. E é "falhou" mesmo :D